# How can I webscrape these ticker symbols from barchart.com?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, stock

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to webscrape the list of ticker symbols from this page: https://www.barchart.com/options/most-active/stocks

My code returns a lot of HTML from the page, but I can't find any of the ticker symbols with CTRL+F. Would be much appreciated if someone could let me know how I can access these!

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
headers = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"}

url = "https://www.barchart.com/options/most-active/stocks"
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = page.text
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import unquote
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0",
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        r = req.get(url[:25])
        req.headers.update(
            {'X-XSRF-TOKEN': unquote(r.cookies.get_dict()['XSRF-TOKEN'])})
        params = {
            "list": "options.mostActive.us",
            "fields": "symbol,symbolType,symbolName,hasOptions,lastPrice,priceChange,percentChange,optionsImpliedVolatilityRank1y,optionsTotalVolume,optionsPutVolumePercent,optionsCallVolumePercent,optionsPutCallVolumeRatio,tradeTime,symbolCode",
            "orderBy": "optionsTotalVolume",
            "orderDir": "desc",
            "between(lastPrice,.10,)": "",
            "between(tradeTime,2021-08-03,2021-08-04)": "",
            "meta": "field.shortName,field.type,field.description",
            "hasOptions": "true",
            "page": "1",
            "limit": "500",
            "raw": "1"
        }
        r = req.get(url, params=params).json()
        df = pd.DataFrame(r['data']).iloc[:, :-1]
        print(df)


main('https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/quotes/get?')
```

Output:

```
    symbol  symbolType  ... tradeTime symbolCode
0      AMD           1  ...  08/03/21        STK
1     AAPL           1  ...  08/03/21        STK
2     TSLA           1  ...  08/03/21        STK
3      AMC           1  ...  08/03/21        STK
4      PFE           1  ...  08/03/21        STK
..     ...         ...  ...       ...        ...
495    BTU           1  ...  08/03/21        STK
496   EVER           1  ...  08/03/21        STK
497   VRTX           1  ...  08/03/21        STK
498   MCHP           1  ...  08/03/21        STK
499    PAA           1  ...  08/03/21        STK

[500 rows x 14 columns]
```